# "Sleep through a single night" vs. "sleep a single night"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, differences, prepositions

> For the next two weeks he did not sleep through a single night.

Can we recast the sentence as follows?

> For the next two weeks he did not sleep a single night.

That is, is the use of *through* mandatory? Is there a difference between these two sentences?

Comment: Are you asking whether the second sentence is grammatical, or whether it means the same thing as the first one?

Comment: yeah @PeterShor I just need to ask whether the two sentences mean the same thing and if not then what's the difference?

Comment: to *sleep through a night* means to go to sleep and stay asleep until morning which is different than just sleeping for a night which can include sleep interruptions.  Your first sentence means he never slept for a complete night any time during the two weeks, the second means he never got a chance to sleep at night at all during the two weeks.

Answer (score 2):

They do not mean the same thing.

> For the next two weeks he did not sleep through a single night.

This means that he *did* sleep, but he did not sleep a whole night without waking up. In other words, he slept very badly.

> For the next two weeks he did not sleep a single night.

This means that he did not sleep at all during a night. Possibly because he had to work, or study, or whatever. He did not sleep *badly*, he did not sleep *at all* (at least during the night - if he worked at night, he might have slept during the day).